# Jquery call same function with parameter value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to upload multiple files from multiple button clicks in asp.net core razor view.

Below is my jquery code which is not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#btnupload1').on('click', myFunction('#fileupload1'));
        $('#btnupload2').on('click', myFunction('#fileupload2'));
        $('#btnupload3').on('click', myFunction('#fileupload3'));
    })

    function myFunction(value) {
        var fdata = new FormData();
        var fileUpload = $(value).get(0);
        var files = fileUpload.files;
        fdata.append(files[0].name, files[0]);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Contract/UpFiles",
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                    $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
            },
            data: fdata,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.length == 0)
                    alert('Some error occured while uploading');
                else {
                    $('#divPrint').html(response);
                }
            },
            error: function(e) {
                $('#divPrint').html(e.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Could you provide what kind of error message you get?

Comment: this is not working as expected, not getting any error

Comment: If you are not getting any error it is probably because your buttons were not bind to any function as you expected. In those situations you may check one of those buttons if there is event by right click ( Inspect )  or from Developer tools / Inspector.

Comment: if i display alert("msg") then it is showing after just load the form. if i remove the alert funciton then it is in silent.

Comment: My requirement is , to call same upload function from different different file upload button.

Comment: Below you may notice three of them calls your same function "myFunction(  )" with different parameters as you have provided up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I was missing the correct way to call. I have resolved my problem to change below code.

Thanks

```
 $('#btnupload').on('click', function () { myFunction('#fileupload'); });
    $('#btnupload2').on('click', function () { myFunction('#fileupload2'); });
    $('#btnupload3').on('click', function () { myFunction('#fileupload3'); });
    $('#btnupload4').on('click', function () { myFunction('#fileupload4'); });
    $('#btnupload5').on('click', function () { myFunction('#fileupload5'); });
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible problem is when you bind your events to those buttons  probably not there.
Solution 1 :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 // your code 

});
```

Another solution if you are creating your buttons dynamically with other JS

```
    $(document.body).on('click', '#btnupload1', function (e) {
 //  
myFunction('#fileupload1')

    })
    $(document.body).on('click', '#btnupload2', function (e) {
 //  
myFunction('#fileupload2')

    })

    $(document.body).on('click', '#btnupload3', function (e) {
 //  
myFunction('#fileupload3')

    })
```